# MYSQL Pull auto increment value

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

Is it possible to add a entry to a database that has an auto increment column and pull the value of the auto increment number as you enter it?

The company I work for is accepting leads, and when a lead comes in, it has to be assigned a unique customer number that can never be duplicated. I would love to use mysql auto increment, but I would need to pull the value it stores as the lead is entered so it can go out to lenders API's along with the unique customer number.

Any help??!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in mysql itself you can use the function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or from php you can use `mysqli_insert_id()` or `PDO::lastInsertId()` to return the last value automatically inserted for an auto-increment column by a previous query.

See: [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: mysqli_insert_id() --- GREAT!! Thank u